# Render realtime changes in Angular across the devices

Tags: angular, real-time, angular6, angular2-changedetection

I'm working on angular app. And I'm looking for rendering the updated list of users(table format) in real time across all the devices once a new user is added from any one of the given device. Any pointers or hints which could help me with this is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do this with only angular application.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do it with only angular you can try with nodejs +socket.io then you can acheive it

thanks